# Apache Drill: No DrillbitEndpoint can be found

Tags: apache-drill, apache-zookeeper

My first time trying to setup Apache drill in a clustered environment.

I have setup a Zookeeper cluster already using 2 machines. When I run a status check for example on one node:

```
bin/zkServer.sh status
```

I get the response:

```
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /opt/zookeeper-3.4.8/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Mode: leader
```

So it's working.

Next I tried getting Drill working in this cluster- I modify the drill-override.conf file and put something like this:

```
drill.exec: {
  cluster-id: "mycluster",
  zk.connect: "localhost:2181,X.X.X.X:2181"
}
```

Where X.X.X.X is the IP of the other machine in the cluster.

It is the same IP I used in zookeeper's zoo.cfg file, which looks like this:

```
server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
server.2=X.X.X.X:2888:3888
```

But when I try to start Drill, I get this error:

```
No DrillbitEndpoint can be found
```

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DRILL-4523] Disallow using loopback address in distributed mode
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-4523

In Drill 1.7, disallow using localhost address in distributed mode. Please check the JIPA info.